# Interfacing a microcontroller digital IO

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator, buffer, optoelectronics

I'm working with some microcontrollers, and I'm quite confused about how to interface the digital I/O. I've already see some projects with opto-couplers on outputs, other ones with buffers, so I'm kind of confused. When should I use each? When should I not use anything?

For me, that is the way that I thought that would be the "safest" mode:

```
(SOMETHING OUT) --> Buffer --> Opto --> (Microcontroller) --> Buffer --> Opto --> (OUT)
```

But, I do not think it's the most efficient way.

Comment: yes that's the safest way. you probably do not need that. but without knowing lots more I can't guess what is needed.

Comment: What sort of signal conditioning you need really depends on what you're doing.  Because it's such a case-by-case thing, it's always OK to ASK.  Opto is safe, but big, slow and expensive.  Direct from the micro is quick, small and cheap but doesn't protect the micro.  There are a variety of in-betweens.

Comment: Opto for safety and isolation from high voltages and/or noise and transients or for driving floating voltages. Buffer for more drive current (or different different logic levels). So if your MCU pin can't put out enough current to drive the opto directly you might throw a buffer in between them. You might also need a buffer to other drive higher current loads like LEDs, transistors, relays, or whatever. Sometimes you need more current to charge the parasitic capacitances on the line fast enough to maintain signal rise/fall times.

Comment: It depends on your system design requirements and limitations.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple enough.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzydHK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Various output options.*

1. If the required load current and voltage is <= the microcontroller's output capability then drive directly from the GPIO pin. (Figure 1a.)
2. If a higher voltage or current is required then use an external transistor to do the heavy duty work. (Figure 1b.)
3. Opto-isolators are used when

   1. Electrical isolation is required between the controller and the load.
   2. "High-side" switching is required.
   3. Some other odd circumstances.

Figure 1c shows the microcontroller controlling a mains lamp via a (simplified) opto-triac control circuit. Note that there is no electrical connection between the microcontroller and the mains voltage.